# How to get the next nearest cell in Excel if the value does not exist?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have to sum values over date range. But if the first date does not exist, Excel sums from the previous date.

[image]

Help me with how to get the next cell address of a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are facing is exactly how [LOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) is defined. "If the `LOOKUP` function can't find the `lookup_value`, the function matches the largest value in `lookup_vector` that is **less than or equal** to `lookup_value`."

But why `LOOKUP` at all? What you probably want can easily be achieved using [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b):

[image]

Formula in `D4`:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&$D$1,A:A,"<="&$D$2)
```